# FileUpload inside jquery dialog, hasfile false

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I have a jquery UI dialog on my page. It contains nothing more than a single asp FileUpload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuAttachment" />
```

The dialog has 1 button "OK". Those button simply closes the dialog

```
$("#attachment-dialog").dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
  });
```

When pressing the save button on my page. Which is an asp.net button the method SaveAttachement is called.

The problem is that fuAttachment.HasFile (the fileupload control) keeps returning false.
If I move the fileupload control outside of the jQuery UI dialog. HasFile = true.

But the control should be inside the dialog. There's no updatepanel inside the specific page.

Comment: Just a guess, but jq.dialog may be moving your upload input outside of the form it belongs to, and appending it elsewhere in the dom.  Solution would be to include the entire <form> inside the dialog.

Comment: @wwwmarty That advice won't work for ASP.NET Web Forms, because Web Forms can only have one form and that form must contain all the server side controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is happening because the dialog is outside of the form.

jQuery UI Dialog has an [appendTo](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) parameter that will ensure the dialog is part of the form.

```
$("#attachment-dialog").dialog({
            appendTo: "form",
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
  });
```